# CSS: Deleting and ignoring respectively all previous properties?

Tags: html, css

Our app will be integrated over an I-Frame and the existing style-file there overwrites some of rules. I know, I could say in for a certain property it is important and not overwrite in my own css-file, like

```
pre {
    width: 200px !important;
}
```

The problem is, I don't know which properties would be overwritten, sometimes it is color, sometimes size or behaviour in media-queries. It is a very big company and there is no chance to modify their `from-different-sources-on-the-fly-patched-up-css-file`, a terrible situation.

Therefore I would like to have a feature like:

```
pre {
   forget_all_your_previous_settings: yes;
   convert_all_properties_to_w3c_standard: yes; 
}
```

Is there a possibility to do that? Our current workaround is to define everything a new and that is a very high time-consuming and cost-intensive issue.

Comment: No, this does not exist in CSS.

Comment: maybe a dirty trick?

Comment: Inline styles with your conditions. There's not automatic conversion of the properties.

Comment: all the different style sheet files will be integrated into a single one, therefore no chance :/ we can only determine the execution order (our style will be integrated as last one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `all: revert !important;`.

> The all property in CSS resets all of the selected element's properties, except the direction and unicode-bidi properties that control text direction.

read more about it **[here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/all/)**

```css
.element {
  width: 300px !important;
  background: black !important;
  color: red !important;
  font-size: 3em !important;
}

.element {
  all: revert !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="element">
  element
</div>
```

[Working Fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/zeevkatz/8Lsfnuvu/)

**Edit:** Not all browsers support, for full support you can you can do **[this](https://github.com/peteboere/css-crush/blob/master/misc/initial-values.ini)**:

```
.element {
    animation : none;
    animation-delay : 0;
    animation-direction : normal;
    animation-duration : 0;
    animation-fill-mode : none;
    animation-iteration-count : 1;
    animation-name : none;
    animation-play-state : running;
    animation-timing-function : ease;
    backface-visibility : visible;
    background : 0;
    background-attachment : scroll;
    background-clip : border-box;
    background-color : transparent;
    background-image : none;
    background-origin : padding-box;
    background-position : 0 0;
    background-position-x : 0;
    background-position-y : 0;
    background-repeat : repeat;
    background-size : auto auto;
    border : 0;
    border-style : none;
    border-width : medium;
    border-color : inherit;
    border-bottom : 0;
    border-bottom-color : inherit;
    border-bottom-left-radius : 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius : 0;
    border-bottom-style : none;
    border-bottom-width : medium;
    border-collapse : separate;
    border-image : none;
    border-left : 0;
    border-left-color : inherit;
    border-left-style : none;
    border-left-width : medium;
    border-radius : 0;
    border-right : 0;
    border-right-color : inherit;
    border-right-style : none;
    border-right-width : medium;
    border-spacing : 0;
    border-top : 0;
    border-top-color : inherit;
    border-top-left-radius : 0;
    border-top-right-radius : 0;
    border-top-style : none;
    border-top-width : medium;
    bottom : auto;
    box-shadow : none;
    box-sizing : content-box;
    caption-side : top;
    clear : none;
    clip : auto;
    color : inherit;
    columns : auto;
    column-count : auto;
    column-fill : balance;
    column-gap : normal;
    column-rule : medium none currentColor;
    column-rule-color : currentColor;
    column-rule-style : none;
    column-rule-width : none;
    column-span : 1;
    column-width : auto;
    content : normal;
    counter-increment : none;
    counter-reset : none;
    cursor : auto;
    direction : ltr;
    display : inline;
    empty-cells : show;
    float : none;
    font : normal;
    font-family : inherit;
    font-size : medium;
    font-style : normal;
    font-variant : normal;
    font-weight : normal;
    height : auto;
    hyphens : none;
    left : auto;
    letter-spacing : normal;
    line-height : normal;
    list-style : none;
    list-style-image : none;
    list-style-position : outside;
    list-style-type : disc;
    margin : 0;
    margin-bottom : 0;
    margin-left : 0;
    margin-right : 0;
    margin-top : 0;
    max-height : none;
    max-width : none;
    min-height : 0;
    min-width : 0;
    opacity : 1;
    orphans : 0;
    outline : 0;
    outline-color : invert;
    outline-style : none;
    outline-width : medium;
    overflow : visible;
    overflow-x : visible;
    overflow-y : visible;
    padding : 0;
    padding-bottom : 0;
    padding-left : 0;
    padding-right : 0;
    padding-top : 0;
    page-break-after : auto;
    page-break-before : auto;
    page-break-inside : auto;
    perspective : none;
    perspective-origin : 50% 50%;
    position : static;
    /* May need to alter quotes for different locales (e.g fr) */
    quotes : '\201C' '\201D' '\2018' '\2019';
    right : auto;
    tab-size : 8;
    table-layout : auto;
    text-align : inherit;
    text-align-last : auto;
    text-decoration : none;
    text-decoration-color : inherit;
    text-decoration-line : none;
    text-decoration-style : solid;
    text-indent : 0;
    text-shadow : none;
    text-transform : none;
    top : auto;
    transform : none;
    transform-style : flat;
    transition : none;
    transition-delay : 0s;
    transition-duration : 0s;
    transition-property : none;
    transition-timing-function : ease;
    unicode-bidi : normal;
    vertical-align : baseline;
    visibility : visible;
    white-space : normal;
    widows : 0;
    width : auto;
    word-spacing : normal;
    z-index : auto;
}
```

Comment: Gorgeous! Thank your very much!